# How to highlight the results of a text in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I highlight a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546761/how-can-i-highlight-a-word)

I have a gridview and a textbox for searching text from a column.
How can I highlight the result of the text in the column.
I've searched and asked and I get hard things to code..would someone give me a simple code something ? thanks

Comment: You could opt for a jQuery method instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example.

Let say that the search box is:

```
txtSearchForMe.Text
```

Then you make the field on the Grid that show the data you won to highlight

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text" >
    <ItemTemplate ><%#GetText(Container.DataItem)%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And the code behind

```
protected string GetText(object oItem)
{
    if(txtSearchForMe.Text.Lenght > 0)
    {
        return DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "cText").Replace(txtSearchForMe.Text, "<b>" + txtSearchForMe.Text + "</b>");
    }
    else
    {
        return DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "cText");
    }        
}
```

This is a simple idea, you can make it more complicate by splinting the search string to array of separated words and highlight them all.